# How to pass javascript var to php var

Tags: php, ajax

I am using Ajax to pass a javascript value to php value.

I am able to retrieve the data on the javascript end, but when using ajax, I cant seem to be able to transfer the data over to a php var. I get: Notice: Undefined index:

```
// the AXAJ/Jquery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
           $("#Change1").change(function() {
               // This toggles the select tag
        var Class_Initial = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            

        $.ajax({
           url: ajaxurl,
           // action is the name of the function in final_cart
           data: { 
                 'Class_Initial' : Class_Initial,
                "action" : "Print_Roster123_function",

           },
           success: function(data) {
               $("#game1").html(Class_Initial);
 

           },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
        });

    });
});
```

My PHP:

```
 <?php
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        // If I have $_POST as $_REQUEST same error
        $a = $_POST['Class_Initial'];
        // How can I echo out Class_Initial?
        echo $a;
    }
?>
```

Comment: First thing to check is your ajax return response or not if not then check is there is any issue with ajax like it is running or not if js work is fine you can check all data in $_POST variable.
For security purpose use wp_verify_nonce too.
If you share your full code will provide a solution.

Comment: I am able to alert the data inside of the succes:function. There does not appear to be any errors with running ajax. However, when I echo out the $_POST, I get a blank value

Comment: Can you share your full PHP code with wp_priv and no_priv.

Comment: where is the PHP that outputs the variable? Note that when you make a request to the server, it loads WordPress from a blank slate, processes and responds, then WordPress/PHP is unloaded and nothing survives, so variables you set in one request are completely unconnected to the same variable in another request. This is in contradiction to how other systems work, e.g. Node JS based websites where there is a single longrunning program that listens for requests in the background. You should also confirm via `console.log` that `Class_Initial` has a value before making an AJAX call

Comment: I also see nothing in your JS code that tells it to use `POST`